# How to call multiple columns from multiple csv file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, operating-system, glob

I have 100 csv file. I want to print particular columns from all the csv file  with the file name. Here in this code I can print all of the csv file.

```
path = r'F:\11 semister\TPC_MEMBER'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
dataStorage = {}
for filename in all_files:
    name = os.path.basename(filename).split(".csv")[0]
    dataStorage[name] = pd.read_csv(filename)
    print(name)
dataStorage
```

Comment: you just want column names ? or rows of specific column(s)?

Comment: Well, you've already created a dataframe from each CSV file. You can print whatever column(s) of those dataframes you want. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: specific column #eshirvana

Comment: @CrazyChucky  I want to print one column from all of my csv file with the file name.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

path = r'folderpath' #provide your folder path where your csv files are stored.
all_csv= glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

data_frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
data_frame['columnname'] # enter the name of your dataframe's column.
print(data_frame)
```